# How do I identify "simple" monochome emojis like ☺?

Tags: unicode

There are a number of Unicode characters categorized as "Extended Pictographic" which have no color and usually appear smaller than "normal" emojis. Here are some examples:

☺ ☻ ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠ ♂ ♀ ♪ ♫ ☼ ↕ ↔

These don't have a full-colour emoji counterpart. Does the Unicode Consortium provide any table or other information that allows me to identify these characters, i.e. to distinguish these monochrome "Extended Pictographic" characters from full-colour "Extended Pictographic" characters? I wasn't able to find such information myself.

Comment: Most _emojis_ are codepoints _above_ [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), e.g. - `☺` (U+263A,  *White Smiling Face*)
- `☻` (U+263B,  *Black Smiling Face*)
- `` (U+1F603, *SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH*)
- `` (U+1F604, *SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES*). Cf. _Emoji & Pictographs_ in https://www.unicode.org/charts/#symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction you're seeing is called "emoji presentation" vs "text presentation." Some characters have both, and may have one or the other be the default.

The file you want is [emoji-data](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt). When you say "these don't have a full-colour emoji counterpart," that's not correct for most of them. They just have default text representation. I'll walk through a few of these to see how to understand them. One of my favorite exploration tools for this is the [Unicode Utilities](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp). You'll want [UTS#51](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/) as well.

### [☺: WHITE SMILING FACE](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=%E2%98%BA&B1=Show)

(Note that in Unicode, WHITE means "not filled in" and BLACK means "filled in" in many cases for historical reasons, going back to Japanese flip phones. They are not actually colors. Similarly, HEAVY means "bold" or "wide.")

- ID: 263A
- Emoji: yes
- Extended_Pictographic: yes
- Emoji_Presentation: no

So there is an emoji form of this, but it's not the default. We have to ask for it by adding U+FE0F (VARIATION SELECTOR-16). With that, this character displays as ☺️.

### [SMILING FACE WITH SMILING EYES](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=%F0%9F%98%8A&B1=Show)

For comparison, see this character, which is a more "traditional" emoji.

- ID: 1F60A
- Emoji: yes
- Extended_Pictograph: yes
- Emoji_Presentation: yes

### [☻: BLACK SMILING FACE](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=263B)

- ID: 263B
- Emoji: no
- Extended_Pictographic: yes
- Emoji_Presentation: no (necessarily, since not Emoji)

So, this is not an emoji at all which means it has no "emoji presentation." It is merely "similar in kind to characters with the Emoji property" (i.e. extended pictographic).

### [↕: UP DOWN ARROW](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=%E2%86%95&B1=Show)

Another example of an Emoji without Emoji_Presentation. The emoji form is ↕️.

### [1: DIGIT ONE](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=1&B1=Show)

And just for a little completeness:

- ID: 0031
- Emoji:yes
- Extended_Pictographic: no
- Emoji_Presentation: no

Digits are also emoji, and can take VS-16 modifier:

- default: 123
- as emoji: 1️2️3️

If you want a browsable list of characters with different properties, see the [Character Property Index](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/properties.jsp).

Comment: White Smiling Face (☺) appears as text for me here and in all text editors I tried, except for when I paste it into the Chrome browser bar. Appending VS-16 doesn't turn it into an emoji for me (same for Digit One, even in your answer, they remain as text.) It works for Up Down Arrow, however. Could this just be buggy implementations? Unicode Utilities renders all of them as emojis per default, btw.

Similarly, Up Down Arrow (U+2195, emoji=yes, ext_pict=yes, emoji_pres=no) renders as text per default but Hammer And Wrench (U+1F6E0, also yes/yes/no) renders as emoji per default where I tried.

Comment: You should expect "\u263a" to display as ☺ (text form) everywhere. "\u263a\ufe0f" should display as ☺️ (emoji form) most places that handle any emoji at all. Unicode Utilities does favor showing emoji presentation even for things where it is not the default. I haven't dug into what its algorithm is for the big image at the top. I don't know if this is entirely the tool or partially the browser. It may be the font order choice in index.css: (font-family: Georgia, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Times New Roman", Times, Symbola, Aegyptus, Code2000,  Code2001,  Code2002, Musica, serif).

Comment: (I said "\u263a" should display as ☺ everywhere, but if you choose the Apple Color Emoji font, then obviously it will render in the emoji form. The actual appearance of emoji is a font matter, not a Unicode matter. Variation Selectors are hints to fonts, they do not fundamentally change the character.)

Comment: The emoji form of DIGIT ONE looks a lot like the text form. The difference is that it's centered in its cell, with a lot more whitespace to make it "fit" better with other emjoi. My "as emoji" example does not have spaces between the digits. Those are the emoji forms of the digits. Try selecting them and you'll see the difference in where the highlighting takes place. The best text editor to test things with is the Mac TextEdit. It's the most powerful and accurate readily-available text layout engine I'm aware of. (It's *really* good, even for a Mac. Much better than Keynote for example.)

Comment: So after some more testing, what I'm seeing appears to be an issue with Chrome. All the examples look correct (according to your explanations) in Firefox and in Safari. I also pasted your answer into TextEdit, Terminal, and iTerm2. Looks good there, too. Interestingly, when I paste it into an HTML textarea element, it looks fine even in Chrome. So I don't know what it is with this Stack Overflow page in Chrome on macOS. Just Hammer And Wrench is always an emoji, no matter what I do. I guess that's indeed a font issue (no text form available). Anyway, thanks for all the feedback!